# Flask connection refused even after port forwarding

Tags: flask, network-programming

I'm trying to access my Flask application outside my local network, but with no success.

I'm running flask with `flask run --host=0.0.0.0.0 --port=3030`

And I forwarded outside connections to port 3030 on my Raspberry Pi 3030 port.
[image: port forwarding]

But when I look up my external IP (let's say it is 80.80.80.80) and try to connect to it using the forwarded port (80.80.80.80:3030) I get an "Connection Refused" error in my browser.

One thing to note is that my raspberry does not have ufw, so there's no firewall to block the connection.

Comment: What's the first column with IP showing? I believe that is the permitted IP. Why don't you run it on 10.0.0.125:3030?

Comment: are you sure your router gets public IP address? Some ISPs do not provide users with public IP and router belongs to local networks of ISP where extra router is exposed into the world. In such case you would try to connect to second router which does not have forwarding configured...

Comment: I'll check with my ISP, thanks @MaximSagaydachny

Comment: there is no need to contact ISP - you can see assigned IP to WAN interface in a web interface of your router.